# Collada bones in Away 3D

Tags: flash, collada, away3d

I am trying to move from papervision-3d (no longer in development) to away-3d with frustration. I've sent several messages to the away 3d team with no response.

my goal is interactive, web-based 3d animation (which i can do successfully in Papervision) by exporting a collada from blender.  That has bones but no animation.  In PV3D, I use "dae.getChildByName" to target those 'bones' and apply transforms (i.e.: rotate, scale,etc); in away3d the model gets totally messed up when the transforms are applied, though it loads fine when static.

I am not skilled in programming so i need to use "classes" already available. Also, I need to use Blender3D (not 3ds, which exports great).

Any suggestions/help/ideas would be great. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please post a link showing the actual problems.  Also, it may help to know how you are trying to move the collada objects/animations.

The actual problem may also be in Blender, so providing a sample model could help.